# Get all possible variations of binary - given a pattern

Tags: c++, c, 64-bit, bit-manipulation, combinations

OK, what I'm trying to do may sound a bit complicated, but I still cannot figure it out :

- Let's say we have an `unsigned long long` 64-bit integer
- I want to set some "Variable"-bit positions and get all possible derived numbers

**E.g.**

```
Pattern = 00000000XXXXX000XX000X 
Positions = 0,4,5,9,10,11,12,13

Result (Pattern, Positions) = {
    0000000000000000000000
    0000000000000000000001
    0000000000000000010000
    0000000000000000010001
    0000000000000000100000
    0000000000000000100001
    0000000000000000110000
    0000000000000000110001
    etc...
}
```

How should I go about that? Any ideas?

Comment: Iterate from 0 to 2^9, convert it to binary, and then use each bit in the number to represent the value of one 'variable bit' in your number. Not very efficient, but easy to implement.

Comment: Hey: I don't understand your criteria for selecting solutions. Maybe you prefer "readable" to "fast", which is certainly acceptable, but few bit hacks are that simple. Anyway, for your viewing pleasure, a complete benchmark with three solutions (the O(n) loop from kmkaplan, an O(1) loop I quickly wrote as a test, my O(1) answer) and a baseline to capture the benchmark overhead. On my laptop, using 5000000 repetitions, I got base 2.9s, noloop 3.2s, fastloop 4.2s, loop 10.5s. Here it is on lws: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2dfnQo$0 (or maybe not)

Comment: @rici I admit I thought it could strike as a bit weird, since it was your second consecutive *correct* answer to a question of mine, which I'm finally deciding not to accept. So, apologies if it was taken the wrong way. As for my criteria, it's not exactly that... Both of your answers were 100% correct and, to be honest, fast. (Btw, I upvoted both of them, and what could probably end up in the final code is *your* code). As for this particular case, the chosen answer is much more constructive for someone reaching this question. Yours may be smart and concise but few will finally understand it.

Comment: Okey-doke. Enjoy the code, then. Personally I think that encouraging someone to use an O(n) algorithm when there is an O(1) algorithm available is not, in the long run, doing them any favours. (You can do a loop O(1), too, as shown in the lws sample, but proving that fact might be intimidating to a novice as well.) Clearly, it's your question and you can do as you will with it.

Comment: @rici Well, you might have a point in the end... (I'm a full-hearted proponent of the as-fast-as-possible-way, especially in a case such as this one (where is execution time **is** important)... so I think this way is more... fair.) No hard feelings I hope. :-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon, none at all. I would usually go for readable over fast if the speed difference is minor, but this one is a difference of more than an order of magnitude. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're too easy.

Make a mask of the bit positions you want to stay constant. On each iteration:

```
x |= mask;
++x;
x &= ~mask;
```

Comment: Could you explain the logic, possibly with an example ?

Comment: Putting in the 1's makes the carry propagate to the next interesting bit. So you're effectively do a distributed increment.

Answer (score 2):

With *n* "variable" bit positions count up in an *n*-bit variable. For each bitpattern loop through the bit positions, map the counter bit position to a corresponding "variable" bit position, set that bitvalue in a `std::bitset`. Or bit-shifting if you like that better.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int positions[] = { 0, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 };

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int length = sizeof(positions) / sizeof(*positions);
  /* There are 2^length possible combinations */
  for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < 1 << length; i++) {
    unsigned long long pattern = 0;
    for (unsigned long long j = i, k = 0; j != 0; j >>= 1, k++) {
      if (j & 1)
        pattern |= 1ULL << positions[k];
    }
    std::cout << std::bitset<64>(pattern) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer and pretty self-explanatory! Just tested it - and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot, buddy! :-)